# Debugging VSIX Projects in Experimental Instance of Visual Studio suddenly causes StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I've spent some time this weekend working on a VSIX (Visual Studio Extension) project, and about some time yesterday the experimental instance began throwing a `StackOverflowException` when starting debug. The exception seems to be thrown from within the `JoinableTaskFactory` class from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading`, specifically from this method:

```
private void ExecuteJob<T>(Func<Task> asyncMethod, JoinableTask job)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be an issue that is caused by the project itself, as **I've tried debugging a new blank VSIX project and I'm continuing to run into the same exception**. I'm really not sure what could be causing this. In the time between when I was able to debug and when I started running into this issue, I hadn't made any changes to the IDE itself (including installing other extensions or updates). I've also tried resetting the experimental instance and doing a fresh install of Visual Studio, but neither has resolved the issue.

At this point I'm pretty stumped... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you have a look at the call stack?

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, but unfortunately a lot of it was from modules that didn't have debug symbols loaded. I ended up adding a breakpoint to the ExecuteJob method that printed the values of the parameters each time the method was invoked. This ultimately helped me figure out that the issue was in the search service, which was being caused by the recursive menu commands that I mentioned in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not exactly sure why the extension was able to persist in the Experimental instance, but it turns out even after all that it was still installed, and *it was the extension after all*. I had mistyped the parent of the extension menu in the command table and set it to the extension menu group, which was causing the menu to get recursively nested within itself. This was causing the visual studio search service to crash in the experimental instance with a `StackOverflowException`. I uninstalled the old version of the extension and everything works perfectly now.